# Parse Id from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm having a strange issue, I have a populated datatable and I'm trying to pass the StoreLicenseId to a method in my controller but the parameter in my method is always null. The StoreLicenseId is in my datatable. Everything looks correct but I just can't get it to work.

**View**

```
<form method="post">
    <input class="btn btn-outline-info btn-1" type="submit" value="Terminal" asp-controller="Terminal" asp-action="TerminalInfo" asp-route-id="@item.StoreLicenseId">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult TerminalInfo(string storeLicenseId)
{
    if (_context.StoreLicenses == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var terminalModel = _context.StoreLicenses.FindAsync(storeLicenseId);
    if (terminalModel == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(terminalModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Add input a name attribute
2.remove route id

```
    <input class="btn btn-outline-info btn-1" type="submit" value="Terminal" asp-controller="Terminal" asp-action="TerminalInfo" name="storeLicenseId">
```

OR:
Use asp-for

Answer (score 2):

You should set your asp-route parameter to the same name of the parameter expected by the controller action, so change this

```
 asp-route-id="@item.StoreLicenseId"
```

to

```
asp-route-storeLicenseId="@item.StoreLicenseId"
```

or change the name in the controller action to be simply *id*